How can I add the Firestore SDK to an Oracle JET project?
TLDR: How can I utilize Google Cloud Firestore in an Oracle Jet project?
I am attempting to add the Firestore client SDK to an Oracle JET project. I have run the following command to add the package to my project:
npm install firebase@10.12.2 --save

After this, I know that the path_mapping.json file needs to be updated, however, I am unsure of what it should contain.
Path_mapping.json file:
"firebase/firestore": {
      "cdn": "3rdparty",
      "cwd": "node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist",
      "debug": {
        "src": ["*.js", "*.map"],
        "path": "libs/@firebase/firestore/index.esm2017.js"
      },
      "release": {
        "src": ["*.js", "*.map"],
        "path": "libs/@firebase/firestore/index.esm2017.js"
      }
    }

TS file:
import { collection, getDocs, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

Can I utilize the Firestore client SDK in an Oracle JET project? If so, what should the path_mapping.json file look like to add it?

You can add the relevant path_mappings after save like this:
    "firebase": {
  "cdn": "3rdparty",
  "cwd": "node_modules/firebase/",
  "debug": {
    "src": "firebase-compat.js",
    "path": "libs/firebase/firebase.js"
  },
  "release": {
    "src": "firebase-compat.js",
    "path": "libs/firebase/firebase.js"
  }
},

Things to keep in mind while adding path mapping is that your output file should be (in most cases) a single .js file. this is enough to get you started , if you are developing in js then
import "firebase"

should give you the working module. However for TS we still need to point the compiler to the declaration files. which you can do like :
    "paths": {
  "ojs/*": [
    "./node_modules/@oracle/oraclejet/dist/types/*"
  ],
  "@oracle/oraclejet-preact/*": [
    "./node_modules/@oracle/oraclejet-preact/*"
  ],
  "oj-c/*": [
    "./node_modules/@oracle/oraclejet-core-pack/oj-c/types/*"
  ],
  "preact": [
    "./node_modules/preact"
  ],
  "firebase": [
    "./node_modules/firebase/compat"
  ]
},

Access:
import firebase from 'firebase';
...
...
constructor() {
// const aa = firestore.
console.log(firebase.firestore);
}

output

as You trying to achieve the connectivity
{
  "firebase": {
    "cdn": "3rdparty",
    "cwd": "node_modules/@firebase",
    "debug": {
      "src": ["**/*.js", "**/*.map"],
      "path": "firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js"
    },
    "release": {
      "src": ["**/*.js", "**/*.map"],
      "path": "firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js"
    }
  }
}


import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

// please add your firebase config Detils
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);


async function getCollectionDocs() {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "your-collection"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
  });
}

getCollectionDocs();

aslo, make sure that paths in the path_mapping.json file match the actual paths in your node_modules directory.

Thanks for your comment, @Lucifer. Various console errors when trying this solution.
GET http://localhost:8000/js/firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8000/js/firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm/firestore.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

did you check the PATH's of file
